# Oracle Apex 4.1 how to create field which is either LOV and text field

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, lov

I came a cross issue when designing new form in Oracle APEX. I was asked to create field which can be a populated by user input or by drop down list(popup LOV). Is there easy way of designing such element ? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A popup LOV might be what you are looking for. Create an item of type popup LOV and set the input field setting on "Enterable.."

Comment: Brilliant! Simple and working solution. I also was wondering about applying Ajax for it.

Comment: You may have a look at plugins: http://www.apex-plugin.com/ 
Sometimes very usefull for specific kind of problems.